# Secuencia de ejecución Query ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, select, subconsultas, exists

Tengo una query que no termina de ejecutar nunca, y necesito guardar todos los registros en una tabla. Estoy trabajando en una BASE DE DATOS de SOLO LECTURA solo puedo hacer CONSULTAS y NADA MAS.
Solución: ejecutar la query por parte, pero estoy fallando en algún lugar
QUERY

```
SELECT    'B' caso_tipo, OBN_ID, OBN_SPO_ID, OBN_TIPO_OBJETO_ID, OBN_OBJETO_ID, OBN_PERIODO, OBN_CUOTA, OBN_FECHA_VTO_ORIGINAL, OBN_SALDO, 
          OBN_PEO_ID_FORMAL, OBN_PEO_ID_MATERIAL, OBN_FAO_ID, OBN_FAO_ID_CUOTA, OBN_ICP_CCO_ID, OBN_ICP_IPO_ID, OBN_VTO_PRORROGADO
FROM      obligaciones@dbl_cldd o
WHERE     o.obn_fecha_baja IS NULL
AND       o.obn_oga_id IN (SELECT   oga.oga_id
                           FROM     obligaciones_genericas@dbl_cldd oga
                           WHERE    oga.oga_fecha_baja IS NULL
                           AND      oga.oga_icp_ipo_id IN (5,600,58)
                           AND      oga.oga_periodo >= '2015'
                           AND      oga.OGA_ICP_CCO_ID IN ('100','200','600','700','580'))
AND       NOT EXISTS (SELECT   1 
                      FROM     movimientos_cuenta_corriente@dbl_cldd mcc 
                      WHERE    mcc.mcc_fecha_baja IS NULL 
                      AND      mcc.mcc_obn_id = o.obn_id 
                      AND      mcc.mcc_tipo_origen IN ('PAO','FAO','CRE','PSV'))--PAO Pago/FAO Es una forma de pago
AND       o.obn_peo_id_material IN ('PC','GEJ')--Estado de pago /PC Pendiente de pago
AND         EXISTS (SELECT     1
                    FROM       obligaciones@dbl_cldd oo
                    WHERE      oo.obn_fecha_baja IS NULL
                    AND        oo.obn_oga_id IN (SELECT    og.oga_id
                                                 FROM      obligaciones_genericas@dbl_cldd og
                                                 WHERE     og.oga_fecha_baja IS NULL
                                                 AND       og.oga_icp_ipo_id = o.OBN_ICP_IPO_ID 
                                                 AND       og.oga_periodo = o.obn_periodo
                                                 AND       og.oga_periodo >= '2015'
                                                 AND       og.OGA_ICP_CCO_ID IN  ('101','201','601','701','581','582'))
                    AND         (
                                    (
                                         oo.obn_peo_id_material IN ('PTET','PTFT','VPPET','VPPFT','VPTET','VPTFT','PPET','PPFT','AFPPG')
                                         AND     EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                                         FROM   movimientos_cuenta_corriente@dbl_cldd mcc 
                                                         WHERE  mcc.mcc_fecha_baja IS NULL 
                                                         AND    mcc.mcc_obn_id = oo.obn_id 
                                                         AND    mcc.mcc_tipo_origen IN ('PAO','FAO','CRE','PSV'))
                                  )
                                  OR     oo.obn_peo_id_material IN ('APCBL','CTE')
                                )
                    AND         oo.OBN_CUOTA NOT IN (50,80,81,90,91,45)
                    AND         oo.obn_objeto_id = o.obn_objeto_id
                    AND         oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id = o.obn_tipo_objeto_id
                    AND         oo.obn_periodo = o.obn_periodo)
```

1er paso: guardar esta parte de la query (antes del exist) en una tabla A

```
CREATE TABLE tabla_A AS

SELECT    'B' caso_tipo, OBN_ID, OBN_SPO_ID, OBN_TIPO_OBJETO_ID, OBN_OBJETO_ID, OBN_PERIODO, OBN_CUOTA, OBN_FECHA_VTO_ORIGINAL, OBN_SALDO, 
          OBN_PEO_ID_FORMAL, OBN_PEO_ID_MATERIAL, OBN_FAO_ID, OBN_FAO_ID_CUOTA, OBN_ICP_CCO_ID, OBN_ICP_IPO_ID, OBN_VTO_PRORROGADO
FROM      obligaciones@dbl_cldd o
WHERE     o.obn_fecha_baja IS NULL
AND       o.obn_oga_id IN (SELECT   oga.oga_id
                           FROM     obligaciones_genericas@dbl_cldd oga
                           WHERE    oga.oga_fecha_baja IS NULL
                           AND      oga.oga_icp_ipo_id IN (5,600,58)
                           AND      oga.oga_periodo >= '2015'
                           AND      oga.OGA_ICP_CCO_ID IN ('100','200','600','700','580'))
AND       NOT EXISTS (SELECT   1 
                      FROM     movimientos_cuenta_corriente@dbl_cldd mcc 
                      WHERE    mcc.mcc_fecha_baja IS NULL 
                      AND      mcc.mcc_obn_id = o.obn_id 
                      AND      mcc.mcc_tipo_origen IN ('PAO','FAO','CRE','PSV'))--PAO Pago/FAO Es una forma de pago
AND       o.obn_peo_id_material IN ('PC','GEJ')--Estado de pago /PC Pendiente de pago
```

2do paso: Todo los registros que devuelva la subconsulta del EXISTS lo guardo en una tabla B

```
SELECT *
FROM   tabla_A
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT 1 
              FROM   tabla_B);
```

¿Cómo Obtengo la TABLA B? De la siguiente manera , saco las columnas que haces el MATCH y las palabras reservadas AND EXISTS

```
AND         EXISTS (SELECT     1
                    FROM       obligaciones@dbl_cldd oo
                    WHERE      oo.obn_fecha_baja IS NULL
                    AND        oo.obn_oga_id IN (SELECT    og.oga_id
                                                 FROM      obligaciones_genericas@dbl_cldd og
                                                 WHERE     og.oga_fecha_baja IS NULL
                                                 AND       og.oga_icp_ipo_id = o.OBN_ICP_IPO_ID 
                                                 AND       og.oga_periodo = o.obn_periodo
                                                 AND       og.oga_periodo >= '2015'
                                                 AND       og.OGA_ICP_CCO_ID IN  ('101','201','601','701','581','582'))
                    AND         (
                                    (
                                         oo.obn_peo_id_material IN ('PTET','PTFT','VPPET','VPPFT','VPTET','VPTFT','PPET','PPFT','AFPPG')
                                         AND     EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                                         FROM   movimientos_cuenta_corriente@dbl_cldd mcc 
                                                         WHERE  mcc.mcc_fecha_baja IS NULL 
                                                         AND    mcc.mcc_obn_id = oo.obn_id 
                                                         AND    mcc.mcc_tipo_origen IN ('PAO','FAO','CRE','PSV'))
                                  )
                                  OR     oo.obn_peo_id_material IN ('APCBL','CTE')
                                )
                    AND         oo.OBN_CUOTA NOT IN (50,80,81,90,91,45)
                    AND         oo.obn_objeto_id = o.obn_objeto_id
                    AND         oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id = o.obn_tipo_objeto_id
                    AND         oo.obn_periodo = o.obn_periodo)
```

ME queda esta query LIMPIA lista para ejecutarla por parte

```
SELECT     1
                    FROM       obligaciones@dbl_cldd oo
                    WHERE      oo.obn_fecha_baja IS NULL
                    AND        oo.obn_oga_id IN (SELECT    og.oga_id
                                                 FROM      obligaciones_genericas@dbl_cldd og
                                                 WHERE     og.oga_fecha_baja IS NULL
                                                 AND       og.oga_icp_ipo_id = o.OBN_ICP_IPO_ID 
                                                 AND       og.oga_periodo = o.obn_periodo
                                                 AND       og.oga_periodo >= '2015'
                                                 AND       og.OGA_ICP_CCO_ID IN  ('101','201','601','701','581','582'))
                    AND         (
                                    (
                                         oo.obn_peo_id_material IN ('PTET','PTFT','VPPET','VPPFT','VPTET','VPTFT','PPET','PPFT','AFPPG')
                                         AND     EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                                         FROM   movimientos_cuenta_corriente@dbl_cldd mcc 
                                                         WHERE  mcc.mcc_fecha_baja IS NULL 
                                                         AND    mcc.mcc_obn_id = oo.obn_id 
                                                         AND    mcc.mcc_tipo_origen IN ('PAO','FAO','CRE','PSV'))
                                  )
                                  OR     oo.obn_peo_id_material IN ('APCBL','CTE')
                                )
                    AND         oo.OBN_CUOTA NOT IN (50,80,81,90,91,45)
```

Creo una tabla_b_1 con la primera parte de la query

```
SELECT     oo.obn_objeto_id,oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id,oo.obn_periodo
                    FROM       obligaciones@dbl_cldd oo
                    WHERE      oo.obn_fecha_baja IS NULL
                    AND        oo.obn_oga_id IN (SELECT    og.oga_id
                                                 FROM      obligaciones_genericas@dbl_cldd og
                                                 WHERE     og.oga_fecha_baja IS NULL
                                                 AND       og.oga_icp_ipo_id = o.OBN_ICP_IPO_ID 
                                                 AND       og.oga_periodo = o.obn_periodo
                                                 AND       og.oga_periodo >= '2015'
                                                 AND       og.OGA_ICP_CCO_ID IN  ('101','201','601','701','581','582'))
AND         oo.OBN_CUOTA NOT IN (50,80,81,90,91,45)
AND  (
oo.obn_peo_id_material IN ('PTET','PTFT','VPPET','VPPFT','VPTET','VPTFT','PPET','PPFT','AFPPG')
                                         AND     EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                                         FROM   movimientos_cuenta_corriente@dbl_cldd mcc 
                                                         WHERE  mcc.mcc_fecha_baja IS NULL 
                                                         AND    mcc.mcc_obn_id = oo.obn_id 
                                                         AND    mcc.mcc_tipo_origen IN ('PAO','FAO','CRE','PSV'))
)
```

Creo otra tabla tabla_b_2

```
SELECT     oo.obn_objeto_id,oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id,oo.obn_periodo
                    FROM       obligaciones@dbl_cldd oo
                    WHERE      oo.obn_fecha_baja IS NULL
                    AND        oo.obn_oga_id IN (SELECT    og.oga_id
                                                 FROM      obligaciones_genericas@dbl_cldd og
                                                 WHERE     og.oga_fecha_baja IS NULL
                                                 AND       og.oga_icp_ipo_id = o.OBN_ICP_IPO_ID 
                                                 AND       og.oga_periodo = o.obn_periodo
                                                 AND       og.oga_periodo >= '2015'
                                                 AND       og.OGA_ICP_CCO_ID IN  ('101','201','601','701','581','582'))
AND         oo.OBN_CUOTA NOT IN (50,80,81,90,91,45)
AND         oo.obn_peo_id_material IN ('APCBL','CTE')
```

LUEGO hago el UNION de ambas tablas tabla_b_2 UNION tabla_b_2 y creo la tabla_B

```
CREATE TABLE tabla_B AS
select *
FROM tabla_b_2
UNION
SELECT *
FROM tabla_b_1
```

Finalmente hago

```
SELECT *
FROM   tabla_A o
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT 1 
              FROM   tabla_B oo
              WHERE         oo.obn_objeto_id = o.obn_objeto_id
              AND         oo.obn_tipo_objeto_id = o.obn_tipo_objeto_id
              AND         oo.obn_periodo = o.obn_periodo);
```

Al hacer esto, en algo estoy fallando por que me trae registros que no deberían aparecer. ¿Cómo podría arreglarlo?

Comment: Has podido identificar en cuál de las tablas llega info que no debería aparecer? Por qué dices que no debería aparecer? Recuerda que sólo vemos lo que nos cuentas, así que no sabemos qué pasa ni qué debería pasar :)

Comment: @Alfabravo mas allá del resultado. Esta secuencia de ejecución de una query seria la correcta? (ejecutarla por parte).

Comment: Pues es que no estableces ninguna relación entre tabla_A y tabla_b, así que traerá un poco de cosas de tabla_A sin más. ¿Cuál es el resultado de select 1 from cualquier_tabla? _Piénsalo_ ;)

Comment: perdon perdon me equivoque lo corrijo .... se me paso por alto

Comment: aun asi no entiendo, si me trae registros diferentes mi query  con respecto a la query original por lo tanto esta query NO ES EQUIVALENTE, quizás estoy fallando en MI PROCESO DE EJECUCION